# Can I create "abstract" tensors in Sagemath?

Tags: symbolic-math, tensor, sage

I would like to, for example, take the exterior derivative of a one-form without specifying the coefficients. For example, if I have a one form

a = fdz + gdx + hdy

how can I calculate da in terms of f_x, f_y, etc. without telling Sage exactly what f,g, and h are?

I have tried looking in both differential forms and tensors sections of the Sage website but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is somewhat possible, but maybe of limited (current utility).

```
sage: U = Manifold(3, 'U')
sage: X.<x,y,z> = U.chart()
sage: f = U.diff_form(2, 'f')
sage: f
2-form f on the 3-dimensional differentiable manifold U
sage: f.exterior_derivative()
3-form df on the 3-dimensional differentiable manifold U
```

So at least there are abstract ones.  But

```
sage: f.components()
...
ValueError: no basis could be found for computing the components in the Coordinate frame (U, (d/dx,d/dy,d/dz))
```

However, I *think* one can get around this by defining an abstract function of three variables.  No guarantees on whether this is 100% accurate, because the relationship of the "chart" variables to the other symbolic variables out there is not clear to me - I have not used `SageManifolds` much.

```
sage: pbi = function('pbi', nargs=3)(x,y,z); pbi
pbi(x, y, z)
sage: type(pbi)
<type 'sage.symbolic.expression.Expression'>
sage: f[0,1]=pbi
sage: f
2-form f on the 3-dimensional differentiable manifold U
sage: f.components()
Fully antisymmetric 2-indices components w.r.t. Coordinate frame (U, (d/dx,d/dy,d/dz))
sage: f.display()
f = pbi(x, y, z) dx/\dy
sage: f.exterior_derivative()
3-form df on the 3-dimensional differentiable manifold U
sage: f.exterior_derivative().components()
Fully antisymmetric 3-indices components w.r.t. Coordinate frame (U, (d/dx,d/dy,d/dz))
sage: f.exterior_derivative().display()
df = d(pbi)/dz dx/\dy/\dz
sage: f[1,2]=pbi^2
sage: f.exterior_derivative().display()
df = (2*pbi(x, y, z)*d(pbi)/dx + d(pbi)/dz) dx/\dy/\dz
```

If these calculations are what you would expect, then I guess you can use them.  A quick surface glance says that at least the +/- seems correct.

```
sage: g = U.diff_form(1, 'g')
sage: g[:] = (pbi,pbi^2,pbi^3)
sage: g.display()
g = pbi(x, y, z) dx + pbi(x, y, z)^2 dy + pbi(x, y, z)^3 dz
sage: g.exterior_derivative().display()
dg = (2*pbi(x, y, z)*d(pbi)/dx - d(pbi)/dy) dx/\dy + (3*pbi(x, y, z)^2*d(pbi)/dx - d(pbi)/dz) dx/\dz + (3*pbi(x, y, z)^2*d(pbi)/dy - 2*pbi(x, y, z)*d(pbi)/dz) dy/\dz
```

See [here](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/40345/differential-forms-best-package/) (but only the manifold version, the other is deprecated) for a lot more examples overall, in addition to the documentation you have already mentioned.